# How to add is_client method to User model in Django with these models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have User, UserClient and Client models like this:

**One client can have many users:**

```
  class Client(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    # Which company the client represents
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    # Address of the company
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    company_size = models.ForeignKey(CompanySize, null=True)

    account_type = models.ForeignKey(AccountType)

    billing_address = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)

    # Billing Information of the client

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class ClientUser(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

Now in the template, I want to do like this:

```
{% if user.is_client %}

{{ do_this }}
```

How to do this?

Comment: What is `user` in your template, is it a User, a ClientUser or a Client?

Comment: Your design is broken: If you have a "Client" model, related to "User", why do you have a "is_client" attribute in the Client model?  You should implement your own User model and add a method "is_client" there, if needed.

Comment: Oh yes, deleted `is_client` from Client model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the "user" in your template is a `django.contrib.auth.User` instance, the simplest solution to add a `is_client()` method to `User` is to monkeypatch `User`:

```
# youmodels.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# your models here...

def user_is_client(user):
    try:
        client = user.client
    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    else:
        return True

User.is_client = user_is_client
```

But as schneck commented, it might be better to have a custom User model if your django version is recent enough.

Comment: `user` is a instance of user from `auth_user`. Your solution seems fine. But not working. I have also updated my model

Comment: It' s working. I have to remove `is_user` from this line `return client.is_user`

Comment: Sorry I meant `client.is_client` of course. But since you deleted this field from you model you now just have to `return True` instead.

Comment: Great sire, +1 again :)